# Postgres UPSERT UPdate using rows values

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique, upsert

If my table looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE public.temperatures (
  temperature_io_id        integer NOT NULL,
  temperature_station_id   integer NOT NULL,
  temperature_value        double precision NOT NULL,
  temperature_current_kw  double precision NOT NULL,
  temperature_value_added  integer DEFAULT 1,
  temperature_kw_year_1   double precision DEFAULT 0,
  /* Keys */
  CONSTRAINT temperatures_pkey
    PRIMARY KEY (temperature_io_id, temperature_station_id, temperature_value)
) WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
  );
```

I'm trying to add values to the table when there is a unique combination of io_id, station_id and temperature. If this combination already exists, i want to update the kw value and add 1 to the value_added field. This will be used to keep a running average of the kw at the temperature.

```
INSERT INTO temperatures
(temperature_io_id, temperature_station_id, temperature_value, temperature_curr_kw)
VALUES
(20,30,40,10)
ON CONFLICT
(temperature_io_id, temperature_station_id, temperature_value)
DO UPDATE SET    
temperature_current_kwh = ((temperature_current_kw * temperature_value_added) + EXCLUDED.temperature_current_kw) / (temperature_value_added + 1),
                        temperature_value_added = temperature_value_added + 1;
```

How can i access the values from the row when im doing the update? I get an ambiguous error when i try to access `temperature_current_kw`?

Comment: I think I figured out a solution. If i put the table name infront of the columns so like `temperatures.temperature_current_kw` that would access the data point that had the insert conflict?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a table alias:

```
INSERT INTO temperatures as t
    (temperature_io_id, temperature_station_id, temperature_value, temperature_current_kw)
VALUES
    (20,30,40,10)
ON CONFLICT
    (temperature_io_id, temperature_station_id, temperature_value)
DO UPDATE SET    
    temperature_current_kw = ((t.temperature_current_kw * t.temperature_value_added) + EXCLUDED.temperature_current_kw) / (t.temperature_value_added + 1),
    temperature_value_added = t.temperature_value_added + 1;
```

As stated in [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html):

> alias
>
> A substitute name for table_name. When an alias is provided, it completely hides the actual name of the table. This is particularly
>   useful when ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE targets a table named excluded,
>   since that's also the name of the special table representing rows
>   proposed for insertion.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what i needed.